# CRC-5 in MATLAB

Tags: crc, matlab, error-detection

How to encode/decode **[CRC-5-EPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Commonly_used_and_standardized_CRCs)** (x^5+x^3+1) in MATLAB?

I've tried:

```
code = encode(msg,n,k,'cyclic/binary', [1,0,1,0,0,1]);
```

But it returns:

> The generator polynomial P cannot produce a cyclic code generator matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `crc.generator`([doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/comm/ref/crc.generator.html)) instead of `encode` :

```
 h = crc.generator([1,0,1,0,0,1])
 code = generate(gen, msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/comm/ref/encode.html (emphasis is mine):

> `code = encode(msg,n,k,'cyclic/fmt',genpoly)` encodes `msg` and creates a systematic cyclic code. `genpoly` is a row vector that gives the coefficients, in order of **ascending powers**, of the binary generator polynomial.